# Update hbm.xml file to hibernate 5 for hibernate.spatial.GeometryType

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-spatial

I have a Location.hbm.xml file with the following line:

```
<property name="coordinates" type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType">
        <column name="coordinates" />
</property>
```

We are updating to hibernate 5, and there is no GeometryType object anymore. What class should I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hibernate 5, Hibernate Spatial is much closer integrated in Hibernate-core then before. Provided your coordinates property is of type JTS Geometry, and hibernate-spatial 5 is on the classpath, it should be resolved automatically. The type has key jts_geometry in the Type Registry

Comment: In other words I should use the following?

    <property name="coordinates" type="jts_geometry">
            <column name="coordinates" />
    </property>

Comment: Got it. The type attribute is optional, so I should just omit it.